# Why does this dictionary generate like this?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, generator

I am making a simple app that schedules a leagues games. I get the number of weeks played, and every team that week needs a matchup. Im not finished, but I was going through testing it the output generates weird.

```
def scheduleMaker(dicty):
    weeks_to_sched = int(input("How many weeks?"))
    #weeks count
    weeks_count = [list(range(1, (weeks_to_sched + 1)))]
    schedule = {}
    #for every week of the season
    for x in weeks_count:
        #add a entry in the dict for this week
        schedule[f"Week {x}"] = {}
        #every team that week needs a matchup
        for j in names:
            #this team needs to be added to week 1 with a matchup
            schedule[f"Week {x}"][j] = [j]
    print(schedule)

scheduleMaker(teams)
```

I want a dictionary for each week created and then the key: values (matchups) in each week's dictionary. Im having trouble with the first lines of the code. Im getting:

```
{'Week [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]': {}
```

Instead of:

```
{'Week 1': {}, 'Week 2': {}, 'Week 3: {}', etc}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to learn how to debug your code and find errors. Adding simple print lines will help you to spot problems

```
print(weeks_count)
print(x)

#produces 
[[1, 2, 3]]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Which means that `x` is equal to the whole array instead of expected int. That is because you added extra brackets to the list and made it array with list as 1st element of array

```
    # not ok
    weeks_count = [list(range(1, (weeks_to_sched + 1)))]
    # ok
    weeks_count = list(range(1, (weeks_to_sched + 1)))
    # best
    weeks_count = range(1, weeks_to_sched + 1)
```

But also you don't need to keep weeks_count list, as you may iterate directly through range (code below)

I would also recommend not missing input, some global `names` variable and logic of creating schedule into 1 function. Better way is to pass all required args into this functions so it has one responsibility

final code and output:

```
def scheduleMaker(weeks_to_sched, names):
    schedule = {}
    for weekNum in range(1, weeks_to_sched + 1):
        schedule[f"Week {weekNum}"] = {}
        for j in names:
            schedule[f"Week {weekNum}"][j] = [j]
    print(schedule)

weeks_to_sched = int(input("How many weeks?"))
scheduleMaker(weeks_to_sched, ['a', 'b', 'c'])

{'Week 1': {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b'], 'c': ['c']}, 'Week 2': {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b'], 'c': ['c']}, 'Week 3': {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b'], 'c': ['c']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
weeks_count = [list(range(1, (weeks_to_sched + 1)))]
```

It creates a list inside of a list so when you iterate over `weeks_count` you have only one element there (one element of the entire range).

Instead, change it to be:

```
weeks_count = list(range(1, (weeks_to_sched + 1)))
```

Bare in mind that in your case, you don't have to convert the range into a list (conversion to a list is useful when you want to iterate over the range more than once), so you can use it directly.

```
weeks_count = range(1, (weeks_to_sched + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `range()` function to be able to loop the way you described.

Try doing this instead

```
def scheduleMaker():
    weeks_to_sched = int(input("How many weeks?"))
    schedule = {}
    #for every week of the season
    for x in range(1, weeks_to_sched + 1):
        #add a entry in the dict for this week
        schedule[f"Week {x}"] = {}
        #every team that week needs a matchup
        for j in names:
            #this team needs to be added to week 1 with a matchup
            schedule[f"Week {x}"][j] = [j]
    print(schedule)
```

Comment: For some reason author started counter from 1 for week names, so probably he may need to use `range(1, weeks_to_sched + 1)`

Comment: Agreed, for the sake of clarity, I'll add in that edit. Thank you! @VitaliyMoskalyuk